# J-Y(ST)Y..LG cable's charachteristic impedance

Tags: cables, characteristic-impedance

First: How to find out (e.g. calculate) the characteristic impedance for the cable mentioned?
Id like to know how to model that cable in e.g. Ltspice, so I would like to know either Z or L' and C'.

Second question is: What is meant by coupling (see pdf fom link): $$K1=80\% \leq \frac{300pF}{100m}$$
[Link to cable's specification I have found so far](https://products.lappgroup.com/online-catalogue/data-communication-systems/telephone-cables/indoor-cables/j-ystylg-indoor-cable.html)

edit1:
@Marko Buršič:
So in order to find out L' and C' I need to calculate from the cables geometry, right?
What about my second question?

Answer (score 0):

The cable is for LF, so it doesn't matter what Zk is, that's why is not documented. For high speed communication there are other cables, ethernet, RS485, CAN, Profibus,....there you have the exact specification.